# Where I can delete custom HTML attributes?

Tags: html, configuration, webstorm

I somehow created custom HTML attributes and now I need to delete them but I can't find it anywhere in the settings list of my custom HTML attributes, so that I could delete them...

Can someone say the place where the attributes are stored?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

please see **Custom HTML tag attributes:** option in **Settings | Editor | Inspections, HTML | Unknown HTML tag attribute**